# calculate averages for 5 min intervals in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, average

I have a table `log` with columns `id`, `myValue`, `myCategory` and `myTimestamp`. Suppose the table is filled like this:

| ID | MYVALUE | MYCATEGORY | MYTIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1 | 2010-11-1 10:00:00 |
| 2 | 20 | 1 | 2010-11-1 10:03:00 |
| 3 | 15 | 2 | 2010-11-1 10:15:00 |
| 4 | 05 | 2 | 2010-11-1 10:19:00 |
| 5 | 30 | 1 | 2010-11-1 10:24:00 |
| 6 | 12 | 1 | 2010-11-1 10:30:00 |

Now I would like to generate a table with an `avg()` for column `myValue` in 5 minute intervals for a specified `myCheck`, starting from the last check entry.

The output for `myCheck = 1` should be like:

| ID | AVERAGE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 30 |
| 3 | 15 |

The output for `myCheck = 2` should be like:

| ID | AVERAGE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |

What is the best way to approach this? I have basic knowledge of MySQL but this puzzles me. Part of the query will be like this I suppose (without the 5 min interval grouping):

```
SELECT
  avg(myValue)
FROM
  log
WHERE
  myCheck = ..
```

How can I use the timestamps to generate 5 min intervals averages? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know mysql, but start with looking at what GROUP BY does.

Comment: Can you explain what `check=1` does? I'm not getting this part.

Comment: check = 1 simply means the average in 5 min intervals for column check with value 1

Answer (score 2):

See [this](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,131939,201089#msg-201089).

```
SELECT
  AVG(myValue),
  from_unixtime(ROUND(myTimestamp / (60*5)) * 60 * 5) as rounded_time
FROM
  myTable
GROUP BY rounded_time
```

Comment: This almost gets me there! I should have mentioned that the timestamp is in Datetime format so this: select AVG(value), from_unixtime(ROUND(unix_timestamp(timestamp) / (60*5)) * 60 * 5) as rounded_time from `log` where `check`=1 group by rounded_time almost gets me there. I would like the 5 min intervals to start from the last timestamp entry for a particular check and not on 00, 05, 10 etc. For example the check 2 intervals should be 10:19, 10:14, etc.

Comment: @Ivo: maybe something like `set @min_1 := min(from_unixtime...` then in your select do `...ROUND((timestamp + @min_1) / (60 * 5)...`

Comment: After trying several solutions to this question, i also ended up with a variation of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe later but a shortest query would be:

```
 SELECT ID, AVG(VALUE) as average, DATE_FORMAT(MIN(timestamp), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') AS tmstamp
   FROM yourtable GROUP BY round(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) DIV (60*5))
```

// use brackets behind DIV to multiply seconds for getting minutes

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is interested here is the answer I've come up with (with help from a colleague).

First create a stored procedure in MysQL like so (original source modified from here http://ondra.zizka.cz/stranky/programovani/sql/mysql_stored_procedures.texy) :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE generate_series (
  iFrom TIMESTAMP, iTo TIMESTAMP, iStep INTEGER )

body:
BEGIN

  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS stamp_series;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE stamp_series ( stamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL);

  IF iFrom IS NULL OR iTo IS NULL OR iStep IS NULL
    THEN LEAVE body; END IF;

  SET @iMax = iFrom;
  SET @iMin = iTo;

  InsertLoop: LOOP
    INSERT INTO stamp_series SET stamp = @iMax;
    SET @iMax = DATE_SUB( @iMax, INTERVAL iStep SECOND);
    IF @iMin > @iMax THEN LEAVE InsertLoop; END IF;
  END LOOP;

END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

then the actual query is like this:

```
CALL generate_series( timestamp1 , timestamp2 , 300);
SELECT stamp, DATE_SUB(stamp, INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) AS stamp_min_5, (  SELECT COALESCE( AVG(value), 0) FROM `table` WHERE `category` = 1 AND timestamp <= stamp AND timestamp > DATE_SUB(stamp, INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) ) AS gem FROM stamp_series;
```

Regards,
Ivo

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   DATE_FORMAT((atimestamp),
      concat( '%Y-%m-%d %H:' , 
            cast(round(minute(atimestamp)) -  round(minute(atimestamp)) % 5 as char))
   )AS rounded_time
   ,avg(price) , count(*) from table
```

This way you can get 5 , 10, 15, 30etc. minute average easily.