# MYSQL Get the average of a column each 10 minutes

Tags: mysql, datetime, group-by, aggregate, average

I have a table `test` containing data with 1 minute step, here is an extract of it:

| DATE_TIME | VALUE_G |
| --- | --- |
| 2016-01-01 00:30:00 | 0.0 |
| 2016-01-01 00:31:00 | 0.0 |
| 2016-01-01 00:32:00 | 0.0 |
| 2016-01-01 00:33:00 | 0.0 |
| 2016-01-01 00:34:00 | 0.0 |
| 2016-01-01 00:35:00 | 0.0 |
| 2016-01-01 00:36:00 | 0.0 |
| 2016-01-01 00:37:00 | 0.0 |
| 2016-01-01 00:38:00 | 0.09 |
| 2016-01-01 00:39:00 | 0.8 |
| 2016-01-01 00:40:00 | 1.1 |
| 2016-01-01 00:41:00 | 1.1 |
| 2016-01-01 00:42:00 | 1.1 |
| 2016-01-01 00:43:00 | 0.77 |
| 2016-01-01 00:44:00 | 0.37 |
| 2016-01-01 00:45:00 | 0.37 |
| 2016-01-01 00:46:00 | 0.37 |
| 2016-01-01 00:47:00 | 0.52 |
| 2016-01-01 00:48:00 | 0.65 |
| 2016-01-01 00:49:00 | 0.4 |
| 2016-01-01 00:50:00 | 0.27 |

I want to get the average of `VALUE_G` every 10 minutes, but I want the average to be calculated like this:

| DATE_TIME_AGG | AVG(VALUE_G) |
| --- | --- |
| 2016-01-01 00:30:00 | 0.0 |
| 2016-01-01 00:40:00 | 0.199 |
| 2016-01-01 00:50:00 | 0.592 |

In the above example, for the first row, the average is calculated for DATE_TIME between "2016-01-01 00:21:00" and "2016-01-01 00:30:00", in the second row : between "2016-01-01 00:31:00" and "2016-01-01 00:40:00" and in the third row between "2016-01-01 00:41:00" and "2016-01-01 00:50:00". How can I achieve this knowing that the table `test` contains a lot of data.

Following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4073342/15648345 I can get part of the work done but, the average is not calculated as I want. Here is the code :

```
select from_unixtime(ROUND(unix_timestamp(DATE_TIME) / (60*10)) * 60 * 10) as DATE_TIME_AGG ,AVG(VALUE_G)
from test
group by DATE_TIME_AGG;
```

Comment: What is the version of your mysql

Comment: Im using Mysql Workbench 6.3

Comment: I think the MySQL Server version is more at issue. Run the query `SELECT VERSION();` to get that.

Comment: @BillKarwin I'm using MySQL version 5.7.20-log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CEIL()` instead of `ROUND()`.

Your `from_unixtime(ROUND(unix_timestamp(DATE_TIME) / (60*10)) * 60 * 10)` way of reducing your `DATE_TIME` values to ten minute buckets for aggregation is close. Because it contains `ROUND()` it maps

```
2016-01-01 00:30 to 2016-01-01 00:30  (minutes 25-34 map to 30)
2016-01-01 00:35 to 2016-01-01 00:30  (minutes 35-44 map to 40)
```

According to your question, you want this mapping.

```
2016-01-01 00:30 to 2016-01-01 00:30    (minutes 21-30 map to 30)
2016-01-01 00:31 to 2016-01-01 00:40    (minutes 31-40 map to 40)
```

So you need a function on `DATE_TIME` to do that particular mapping. This, I believe, does the trick for you, by using `CEIL()` in place of `ROUND()`.

```
  from_unixtime(CEIL(unix_timestamp(DATE_TIME) / (60*10)) * 60 * 10)
```

Check it out here.  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ufuCQ82vYc6oueBnkNbAJ5/0

Answer (score 1):

You can try below query

```
SELECT date_format(date_time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00')  +
            interval (minute(date_time) - case when minute(date_time) mod 10 = 0 then 0  else (-10+minute(date_time) mod 10)  end  ) minute as datestamp,
avg(value_g)
    FROM test
    group by 1
    order by 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, your query aggregates the file to the desired timestamps however, when it comes to the average, it is calculated for date_time between "2016-01-01 00:30:00" and "2016-01-01 00:39:00" for the first row, between "2016-01-01 00:40:00" and "2016-01-01 00:49:00" for the second row, and between "2016-01-01 00:50:00" and "2016-01-01 00:59:00" for the third row. Is there a way to get the average for the desired timestamps?

Comment: try the current one. you have tried previous. i have updated the same few minutes ago